# In what situation is it appropriate to NOT have an account on an opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, account

If an opportunity is a possible sale, and an account is someone you do business with, in what situation is it appropriate to not have an account attached to an opportunity?

Surely you can't have an opportunity to make a sale without having someone to sell to?

I just want to use this information to decide whether the account field on an opportunity should be compulsory or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF things are related to Sale, you must have account to be associate with opportunity, 
but there might be scenario where you have to associate opportunity with Lead, in that case account association may not be useful.

As per my knowledge, if you there are such scenario, add `Recordtypes` and associate different opportunity `page-layouts` with/without account mandatory.

> What is an Opportunity?
>
> Opportunities are the sales and pending deals that you want to track.
>   By adding opportunities, you are also building your “pipeline,” which
>   will contribute to your forecast. You can also link opportunities to
>   campaigns to help measure the ROI of your marketing programs. In
>   addition, you can create quotes, which show proposed prices for
>   products and services, from an opportunity.